# Difference between copied and cloned on Rust iterators

Tags: rust, iterator, copy, clone

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the [`copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) and [`cloned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) methods on Rust's [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait. Looking at the docs on [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), I can see that it...

> Differs from Copy in that Copy is implicit and extremely inexpensive, while Clone is always explicit and may or may not be expensive. [...] Since Clone is more general than Copy, you can automatically make anything Copy be Clone as well.

...but for iterators both methods are explicit so what's the point of `copied()`? Should I just always use `cloned()` as it will work in the more general case?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I managed to find (thanks to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493729/peter-hall)!) [this pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/56534) which explains the original reasoning behind adding `copied()` in addition to `cloned()`...

> The intent of copied is to avoid accidentally cloning iterator elements after doing a code refactoring which causes a structure to be no longer Copy. This is a relatively common pattern, as it can be seen by calling `rg --pcre2 '[.]map[(][|](?:(\w+)[|] [*]\1|&(\w+)[|] \2)[)]'` on Rust main repository. Additionally, many uses of cloned actually want to simply Copy, and changing something to be no longer copyable may introduce unnoticeable performance penalty.

Comment: This seems like it would be the case. Not a bad answer 

Answer (score 12):

> Should I just always use cloned() as it will work in the more general case?

Often, the Rust optimiser will be able to figure out that a clone can be replaced with a faster copy. However, this isn't guaranteed, so use `copied()` where you can, to make sure you end up with the fastest binary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I created a simple (and useless) example [here](https://gist.github.com/rust-play/4f4dfce0038e58ded9c8a7a465f1c18a) to test that, but Clippy doesn't seem to warn me that I could use `copied()` instead of `cloned()`...

Comment: @Zak It seems you are right. Clippy  can [suggest the most appropriate of  `copied` or `cloned`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/pull/3970), but doesn't [_currently_](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/3870) suggest using `copied` when you are already using `clone`.

Comment: Ah okay, that's really helpful... also allowed me to find [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/56534) which explains the original intent of `copied()`

Comment: clippy warnings for this seem to be in place now (at least on nightly), seee https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#cloned_instead_of_copied